# Unbinding votes for moderators?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderators

If a moderator finds a question that they don't **think** should be allowed, but aren't sure, if they voted to close, it would be immediately closed. Shouldn't they just be able to vote like a normal user to make sure that others agree with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been [asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote) and is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).